# Android Paypal dependency UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:Execution failed for task dexDebug

Tags: android, paypal

I'm developing an Android application and want to integrate Paypal.
When I'm compiling I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:Pick & Park:assembleDebug]
:Pick & Park:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:Pick & Park:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Pick & Park:compileDebugSources
:Pick & Park:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Pick & Park:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':Pick & Park:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 10.726 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My build gradle dependencies:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pickandpark.pickandpark"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.4'
}
```

So I definitely know it has something to do with the Paypal dependency. I think I have to exclude some dependency from Paypal, I already tried to exclude Gson from paypal but it doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Lennart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need ads, identity and gcm then try removing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Error most probably due to the 65k limit. Also enable [MultiDex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: Removing unnecessary dependencies and enable MultiDex fixed the problem. Thank you very much!